# Replace NA in rows using coalesce-like function

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to see if I can use `dplyr`'s `coalesce` or something like it to combine rows in the same way `coalesce` combines columns.

I found some other similar posts but none that answer my question.

Here's a toy sample:

```
df <- read.table(sep = "|", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F, text = 
"a|NA|NA|d|NA
NA|b|NA|NA|e
a|NA|c|NA|e
1|2|3|4|5
1|2|3|4|5
1|2|3|4|5
1|2|3|4|5")

> df
    V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
1    a <NA> <NA>    d <NA>
2 <NA>    b <NA> <NA>    e
3    a <NA>    c <NA>    e
4    1    2    3    4    5
5    1    2    3    4    5
6    1    2    3    4    5
7    1    2    3    4    5
```

I would like to combine rows 1, 2 and 3 into a single row that I can use as headers. The output should look like this:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  a  b  c  d  e
2  1  2  3  4  5
3  1  2  3  4  5
4  1  2  3  4  5
5  1  2  3  4  5
```

I was hoping something like this would work:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  coalesce(1,2,3) %>% 
  slice(-c(1:2))
```

This worked but it feels clunky:

```
df %>% 
  slice(1:3) %>% 
  fill(everything(), .direction = "down") %>%
  slice(3) %>% 
  bind_rows(df %>% 
              slice(-c(1:3)))
```

I'd like something more straightforward and elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```r
df %>% slice_tail(n = 4) %>% 
  set_names(
    df %>% slice_head(n = 3) %>% map_chr(lift_dv(coalesce))
  )
#>   a b c d e
#> 1 1 2 3 4 5
#> 2 1 2 3 4 5
#> 3 1 2 3 4 5
#> 4 1 2 3 4 5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

---

**Explanation**

The first three rows should be used to figure out the column names. We can
extract them with `slice_head()`.

```r
df %>% slice_head(n = 3)
#>     V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
#> 1    a <NA> <NA>    d <NA>
#> 2 <NA>    b <NA> <NA>    e
#> 3    a <NA>    c <NA>    e
```

Now we need to figure out a way of applying coalesce on each of the columns
in the slice. We could use a `summarise` and `across`, but since we’re not
looking for a dataframe as the output, i’d prefer to use map. If we just map
an identity function to the slice we can see how map works with a datframe as
the input.

```r
df %>% slice_head(n = 3) %>% map(~.)
#> $V1
#> [1] "a" NA  "a"
#> 
#> $V2
#> [1] NA  "b" NA 
#> 
#> $V3
#> [1] NA  NA  "c"
#> 
#> $V4
#> [1] "d" NA  NA 
#> 
#> $V5
#> [1] NA  "e" "e"
```

As you can see, a dataframe is actually just a kind of list with vectors of
equal length. The `map` functions are therefore very useful if we want to
apply something to every single column in a dataframe.

Now we need to figure out how we can use coalesce on these vectors. If we
manually test the first case (`$V1`), we see that there is a minor issue.

```r
coalesce(c("a", NA, "a"))
#> [1] "a" NA  "a"
```

Nothing happens?! This is because coalesce takes its arguments as dynamic dots

```r
coalesce("a", NA, "a")
#> [1] "a"
```

This means we need to figure out a way of unpacking the vector. For this we
can either use !!! to unpack the vectors (you can read about it
[here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#tidy-dots)) or
alternatively use the composition helpers from
[purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/lift.html) which can convert
functions to take list, dots, or vectors. Coalesce takes dots, we want it to
take vectors, which means that we should use `lift_dv`.

```r
x <- c("a", NA, "a")
coalesce(!!!x)
#> [1] "a"
lift_dv(coalesce)(x)
#> [1] "a"
```

Comment: I had never seen `map_chr(lift_dv(coalesce))` but this seems like a useful pattern. I didn't realize `purrr::map` would iterate over columns of a data.frame, and I had never seen `purrr::lift_` for changing the way functions accept arguments. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the OP did not ask for a, b, c . . to be the column names, but I wonder if this is actually what was desired.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on here? I am not familiar with lifting functions. I just read about them a bit but I'm not familiar with dots either so I'm a bit lost. As for naming the columns, I would have had to do that anyway but I see why you had to do that here since the output of your main code was the first row I asked for.

Comment: I added an explanation that hopefully should make it more clear.

Comment: That's really cool, thanks. Great solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(.x, is.na(.x), unique(.x[!is.na(.x)[1:3]])[1]))) %>%
  row_to_names(row_number = 1) %>%
  slice(-c(1:2))

  a b c d e
1 1 2 3 4 5
2 1 2 3 4 5
3 1 2 3 4 5
4 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look elegant but maybe an alternative -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  slice(1:3) %>% 
  summarise(across(.fns = ~na.omit(.)[1])) %>%
  bind_rows(df %>% slice(-(1:3)))

#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  a  b  c  d  e
#2  1  2  3  4  5
#3  1  2  3  4  5
#4  1  2  3  4  5
#5  1  2  3  4  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using built-in functions and the native pipe operator:

```
df[1:3, ] |> 
  sapply(function(x) na.omit(x)[1]) |> 
  rbind(df[-(1:3), ])

#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1  a  b  c  d  e
# 4  1  2  3  4  5
# 5  1  2  3  4  5
# 6  1  2  3  4  5
# 7  1  2  3  4  5
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `invoke` with `coalescse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(janitor)
df %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), ~ c(invoke(coalesce, .[1:3]), .[-(1:3)]))) %>% 
    row_to_names(1) %>%
    as_tibble %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
      a     b     c     d     e
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     2     3     4     5
2     1     2     3     4     5
3     1     2     3     4     5
4     1     2     3     4     5
```

---

Or another option with `fill`

```
library(tidyr)
library(janitor)
df %>% 
    fill(everything(), .direction = 'downup') %>%
    row_to_names(1) %>%
    filter(across(everything(), ~ cur_column() != .))
  a b c d e
1 1 2 3 4 5
2 1 2 3 4 5
3 1 2 3 4 5
4 1 2 3 4 5
```